# Is it necessary to check for subscribed events when wiring up event handlers?

Tags: c#, webforms, vb.net-to-c#

I'm converting some custom server controls from VB to C#.  In one control, this event exists:

```
Private Sub MyControl_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    ' ...
End Sub
```

From my research elsewhere today, I know that in C# this can be achieved by:

```
public MyControl()
{
    Init += MyControl_Init;
}
private void MyControl_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

When checking against different auto-conversion tools, one in particular ([InstantC#](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_CSharp.html)) does things quite differently:

```
public MyControl()
{
    SubscribeToEvents();
}

private bool EventsSubscribed = false;
private void SubscribeToEvents()
{
    if (EventsSubscribed)
        return;
    else
        EventsSubscribed = true;

    this.Init += MyControl_Init;
}
```

I understand that this code checks to see if the events are already subscribed.  My question is, is there any advantage of an EventsSubscribed check over the previous version?  When a server control is instantiated in a page, surely the constructor is only used once anyway?  Or, have I missed something obvious that the online conversion tools are lacking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're sure it's only going to be added once and in one place, like in the constructor, then you don't need to check if it's already subscribed - because it can't be.

Comment: *"it's only going to be added once"* - Are you referring to the logic for subscribing, e.g. the events are only wired up once in the constructor and I'm sure this can't happen elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. If the event could be assigned dynamically, rather than use a flag I would probably prefer to unsubscribe and then resubscribe it anyway.

Comment: So you would call `this.Init +- MyControl_Init;` and then `this.Init += MyControl_Init;`?  I assume an event can be subscribed twice or more?  Also, if you call `this.Init -= MyControl_Init;` and it isn't subscribed already, will it throw?

Comment: I'm thinking `EventsSubscribed` isn't brilliant because its `private` and as you say could still be subscribed externally.  So is it best practice to check for existing subscriptions before adding/removing?